# C - How to skip rest of the string using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

```
9.9999          $ X
16              $ Y = 2^4
32              $ Y = 2^5
```

Or Input might be like this in file

```
9.99999         $ X some string will be here 
25000000        $ Y = some numbers or string 
2500            $ Y = some numbers or string
```

Now I want to only scan first column number's as double and integer using scanf in C. How to do that ?

Comment: If the format is line oriented, you will thank yourself later if you read the lines using `fgets` into a buffer, and then extract data from the buffer using `sscanf`.  You can keep an accurate line count and give a diagnostic pinpointing the line number if something is wrong (like scanf not being able to extract an integer).

Comment: If you want to read in a line and parse it, why not start with a function that reads in a line?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz :)

Comment: Detail: `scanf()` does not read C _strings_.  It reads `stdin` where the rare null character on input has no special meaning.  The usual thought of string with`scanf()` is reading until `'\n'`. `sscanf()` reads a _string_.  So do you want to know about reading characters with `scanf()` or a _string_ with `sscanf()`?  A robust answer has subtle differences depending on your selection.  All in all , your _best_ approach is to abandon this goal and follow this [@Kaz comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009690/c-how-to-skip-rest-of-the-string-using-scanf#comment67297454_40009690)

Comment: ... and easily dump the unused part of the line, as question title.

Comment: @Kaz thanks, done with `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: Be sure to check the return value of `sscanf`; it's informative. Also, watch out for out of range values. Conversion like `%d` invokes **undefined behavior** if the input is out of range. IIRC, the only way to work around that in the `scanf` functions is by limiting the field width.